# how to select from multiple FIT image configurations using barebox bootloader

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto, boot, device-tree, barebox

I am using barebox bootloader and Fitimage which contains 1 kernel and two device trees. i want to select device tree based on HW version. I already know the  HW version, But how can i choose the configuration from Fitimage.

Below is the fitimage.its file.  I want to choose configurations in Fitimage based on HW version , so that we load correct dtb file.

please let me know how we can do this?.

```
{
    description = "fitImage for kernel and two device tress";
    #address-cells = <1>;
    images {
        kernel-1 {
            description = "Linux kernel";
            data = /incbin/("/build/tmp/deploy/images/zImage");
            type = "kernel";
            arch = "arm";
            os = "linux";
            compression = "none";
            
            
            hash-1 {
                algo = "sha256";
            };
        };
        fdt-comm-a.dtb {
            description = "Flattened Device Tree blob";
            data = /incbin/("/build/tmp/deploy/images/comm-a.dtb");
            type = "flat_dt";
            arch = "arm";
            compression = "none";
            
            hash-1 {
                algo = "sha256";
            };
        };
        fdt-comm-b.dtb {
            description = "Flattened Device Tree blob";
            data = /incbin/("/build/tmp/deploy/images/comm-b.dtb");
            type = "flat_dt";
            arch = "arm";
            compression = "none";
            
            hash-1 {
                algo = "sha256";
            };
        };
    };
    configurations {
        default = "comm-a.dtb";
         comm-a.dtb {
            description = "1 Linux kernel, FDT blob";
            kernel = "kernel-1";
            fdt = "fdt-comm-a.dtb";
            
            
            
            signature-1 {
                algo = "sha256,rsa4096";
                key-name-hint = "FIT-4096";
                sign-images = "kernel", "fdt";
                signer-name = "customer";
                signer-version = "vPD20.0.0";
            };
        };
        
        comm-b.dtb {
            description = "2 Linux kernel, FDT blob";
            kernel = "kernel-1";
            fdt = "fdt-comm-b.dtb";
            
            
            
            signature-1 {
                algo = "sha256,rsa4096";
                key-name-hint = "FIT-4096";
                sign-images = "kernel", "fdt";
                signer-name = "customer";
                signer-version = "vPD20.0.0";
            };
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: Apparently this was omitted from the barebox user manual until version 2023.05.0, but you can select a specific configuration by appending the configuration name to the image name separated by `@`. See the description of the `bootm` command in the user manual. The example given in the user manual is `/dev/mmc0.fit@conf-imx8mm-evk.dtb`. Prior to barebox 2016.03.0 it was necessary to specify a number after the `@` instead of a name.

Comment: @Ian Abbott: Can i execute this command from bootloader console ?. I executed like barebox@phytec-imx6-SOM-NAND: global.bootm.image="/dev/nand0.root.ubi.kernel0@comm-a.dtb".       after this i executed bootm command . but it shows error like could not open /dev/nand0.root.ubi.kernel0: No such file or directory. please tell me what steps i am missing here

Comment: Is there a `/dev/nand0.root.ubi.kernel0`? What does filetype `/dev/nand0.root.ubi.kernel0` say? Is `CONFIG_BOOTM_FITIMAGE=y`?

Comment: @IanAbbott: Issue was solved. I just modified the bb append file with the commad  global.bootm.image=/dev/nand0.root.ubi.kernel0@comm-a.dtb  based on HW vesrion , then it worked as expected

Comment: @chandrashekar you should post this as answer and mark the question answered.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was solved. I just modified the bb append file with the command:

```
global.bootm.image=/dev/nand0.root.ubi.kernel0@comm-a.dtb
```

This is based on the hardware version, then it worked as expected.